# Are there any non-fatal javascript errors I can use for testing..?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using window.onerror, and window.onbeforeunload to pass all the errors encountered in the users session with AJAX, I'm trying to test it, and I need to create some javascript errors to test if it is catching it I've tried things like var a = b; (where b doesn't exist) problem is these errors seems to be fatal and stop any further processing...

Can anyone think of a decent way to cause some errors without stopping the processing of the script?

```
ErrorManager: (function () {
        function Init(message) {
            InitErrorHandler();
            InitAjaxHandler();


        }
        function InitErrorHandler() {
            Data.ErrorHandlerText = "";
            Data.ErrorHandlerCount = 0;
            window.onerror = function(errorMessage, url, line) {
                Data.ErrorHandlerText +"Error: "+(Data.ErrorHandlerCount+1)+" \n\n";
                //Get error specific info
                Data.ErrorHandlerText += escape(errorMessage) + "\n";
                Data.ErrorHandlerText +=  escape(url) + "\n";
                Data.ErrorHandlerText +=  escape(line) + "\n";
                Data.ErrorHandlerCount++;
            }
        }
        function InitAjaxHandler() {
            window.onbeforeunload = function() { //when browser closed
                if(Data.ErrorHandlerCount > 0) {
                    SendErrorsToAjax();
                }
            }
        }
        function SendErrorsToAjax() {
            PrepareErrorsForAjax();
            $.getJSON(Interface.PrefixUrl('/sendjserrors/'+Data.ErrorHandlerText), AjaxCallback);
        }
        function AjaxCallback(response) {
            console.log('response of js error ajax request '+response);
        }
        function PrepareErrorsForAjax() {
            var preText = "A user has encountered a few errors: \n\n";
            //Get session info
            var userAgent, activePageID;
            userAgent = escape(navigator.userAgent);
            preText += "User agent: "+userAgent+" \n";
            if($.mobile.activePage != null) {
                activePageID = $.mobile.activePage.attr('id');
                preText += "Page ID: "+activePageID+" \n";
            }

            preText += "\n The following errors were encountered:\n\n";
            Data.ErrorHandlerText = preText + Data.ErrorHandlerText;
        }
        return {
            Init: Init,
            SendErrorsToAjax: SendErrorsToAjax
        }
    })(),
```

Comment: have you tried putting a console.log in the window.onerror handler to see if it is even getting hit?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "fatal" error.  All errors are created equal (except stack overflow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
throw new Error( 'No worries. Just testing...' );
```

You do have to catch it though if you don't want your program to break.

Answer (score 4):

All errors are considered fatal in JavaScript. The current code block (`<script>` tag or external file) is exited and the page continues from the `</script>` tag onwards.

I am not sure whether a `try...catch` block would trigger `onerror`, though.

Answer (score 1):

thanks guys, had a play around after the things you said, as Kolink says, once an error has been encountered, the script basically exits which is far less than ideal.

You can test the onerror thing by:

```
setTimeout("Interface.ErrorManager.SendErrorsToAjax()", 2000);
var a = b; //create an error
//script exists here, but the timeout still bounces in in a few seconds
```